# Docker Toolbox Terminal/Git Bash problems with backspace

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

Until recently, I was able to use an .inputrc file for defining the backspace key as meaning delete-char in bash but a few days ago, Docker Toolbox updated automatically and now bash doesn't work anymore.
Here is what I'm doing

1. Start the "Docker Quickstart Terminal"
2. Run "docker-machine ssh"

At this point, I'm in a normal shell i.e. /bin/sh and the backspace works perfectly, but when I switch to bash, it suddenly stops working. Here is my .inputrc file, not sure if it helps, it worked before the update

```
set completion-ignore-case on

# ctrl-left/right
"\e[1;5C": forward-word   # ctrl + right
"\e[1;5D": backward-word  # ctrl + left 
"\e\e": kill-whole-line

DEL: delete-char
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
```

I'm using Windows 10 with the falls creator update.

- Docker Toolbox: v18.01.0-ce
- Bash: GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release
- Terminal: Windows cmd.exe

I'm going to try identify the last version when it worked, but what I would like to know is if something changed in recent Docker Toolbox versions or if I just did something wrong.

Edit:
I tested around and apparently the boot2docker version 17.12 introduces this regression.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a bug and I didn't do anything wrong. Tracked here: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/1299